# How can I deploy a Shared Dataset from VS2008 to SharePoint 2010 running in Integrated mode with Reporting Services?

Tags: sharepoint-2010, ssrs-2008

Our SharePoint instance has been set up to run integrated with Reporting Services. I am able to create document libraries with the correct content types. I have one called DataSources which is set to allow content types Report Data Source, Report Builder Model and Report Builder Report. The other is called Reports which is set to allow the Report Builder Report content type.

In VS2008 I have my SSRS project which the the project deployment settings as follows:

```
TargetDatasetFolder = "http://mysharepoint/sites/mysite/DataSources"
TargetDataSourceFolder = "http://mysharepoint/sites/mysite/DataSources"
TargetReportFolder = "http://mysharepoint/sites/mysite/Reports"
TargetReportPartFolder = "http://mysharepoint/sites/mysite/DataSources"
TargetServerURL = "http://mysharepoint/"
TargetServerVersion = SQL Server 2008 R2
```

When I deploy the Shared Data Source it works fine, shows up in the library perfectly.
When I deploy the Shared Datasets, I get no error but nothing shows up on the server at all. The output log looks like this:

```
Deploying to http://mysharepoint/
Deploy complete -- 0 errors, 0 warnings
```

Contrast that to the Shared Data Source:

```
Deploying to http://mysharepoint/
Deploying data source 'http://mysharepoint/sites/mysite/DataSources/SharedDataSource.rsds'.
Deploy complete -- 0 errors, 0 warnings
```

When I deploy the report, it complains that the Shared Datasets are not present. And what is worse, if I go and upload the Shared Datasets to the server manually, I still get the error when deploying the report that it can't find the Shared Datasets at the addresses I know they are sitting!

Is there some additional configuration that has to happen to get Shared Datasets to work with SharePoint in integration mode? Or is this just a buggy feature I need to avoid.

It turns out if I upload everything manually, and then go in and manually set the DataSource and DataSet links it will work.

Comment: I just realized that the final line in the output for the deploy of the Shared Dataset says 1 failed, but there is no error at all.

Answer (score 0):

Manually :
After u uploaded rdl,rsd,u should do some ext updating operation .
1. U should update dataset' datasource to  new Sharepoint format like: http:// -[spsite]/[datasource name]. Just choose the datasource u created.
2. u should update rdl'dataset ref to new Sharepoint format like : http:// [spsite]/[datesetname].Just choose the dataset u created.

Auto publish by SSDT Tools:
Create libs in sharepoint site.Config it in SSDT deploy property page,click deploy.For more details U can turn out to book .
As I see, u set TargetServerURL to a wrong target,it's not a site url.U can try to set it to http:/ /my-sharepoint/sites/mysite/ . Haha,I'm not sure,suggest u deep in to the book.!

Ref:
http://www.zhongdaiqi.com/deploy-report-in-sharepoint-2013/